# Why each time Higgs boson decays differently?

Tags: standard-model, higgs

Why the higgs boson and all other particles decays differently for example H->ZZ, H->WW, H->YY, H->bb.

How different particles are created from one particles?

Comment: it is a course on particle physics you are requesting. have a look https://pauline.web.cern.ch/pauline/presentations/ICWES14-PaulineGagnon.pdf

Comment: A decay will be to a superposition of the different possible decay products. You then observe the possible decay products with the probabilities given by the modulus squared of the terms in the superposition.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the higgs boson and all other particles decays differently for example H->ZZ, H->WW, H->YY, H->bb.

The Higg is an elementary particle in the [elementary particle table of the standard model of particle physics:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

[image: elempaert]

There exists the equivalent for antiparticles for the three left columns , and for colors for the quarks. Lots of quantum numbers that have to be conserved.

Note that there are quantum numbers and a mass that accompany each particle. There are stringent rules for conservation of these quantum numbers  depending on the possible exchange forces involved, of which there are three in the standard model : the electromagnetic, the weak, and the strong.

> Note that as far as we now know,   all  matter is composed out of these elementary particles,

Each particle that can decay follows the rule of conservation of energy and momentum the rule of the conserved quantum numbers according to the interaction responsible for the decay, and then enter the probabilities of the interaction which can be calculated using the Lagrangian of the standard model.

Of the elementary the Higgs the Z and the W can decay into pairs of 
particle antiparticle, following quantum number conservation laws, according to probabilities given by the calculations for the interaction some have high probability ,as for Higgs to  b b_bar, and some are smaller, as the gamma gamma channel.

> How different particles are created from one particles?

Once the conservation laws are fulfilled it is only the probabilities that make a channel improbable. The Higgs could decay into four protons and four antiprotons (quantum numbers and energy allow it), but the probability due to the complexity of all the interactions needed to get such a channel is minuscule.